# Do Redis keys expire while being read?

Tags: redis

What will happen if key expires when some process is reading the key? Does redis allows to read the key in this scenario? what will be its behavior/return value if key is deleted when process is reading the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis is single-threaded, so only one request is being processed at a time. If you're able to read it, the read will complete before the delete/expiration is performed. Any expiration, deletion, or alteration operations will happen sequentially after.